# What’s the difference between 해 and 살 and 년?

Tags: difference

What’s the difference between 해 and 살 and 년?? They all mean year(s), right?

Eg. 세 살  or 다섯 해 or 매년

I figure the first is more general, the second is for age and the third is for phrases like the above, ‘every year’. Am I close?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 년 :

1) counting year

2002년 월드컵 Wolrd cup at 2002 year

나는 1997년이 되면 10살이 된다 I will be ten yeas old at 1997

2) 년 = 365 days

몇 년동안 공부했니 ? How many years do you spend for your study ?

> 해 :

1) during 365 days

올 해안에 돈 벌수 있을까 ? Can I earn money in this year ?

해가 바뀌다. This year is gone.

2) 365 days

몇 년동안 공부했니 ? = 몇 해동안 공부했니 ?

> 살 : counting age

너는 몇살이니 ? How old are you ?

Comment: **NOTE** When you can use either `년` or `해`, you would want to stick to `년` in most cases. Using `해` as a unit word sounds literary and even a bit archaic.

Comment: I would not want to stick to 년. Why do you think ?

Comment: Because you cannot use `해` everywhere. While its use is limited, `년` is almost universal. The two are not interchangeable in nuance and usage. `십 년만 지나도` - `열 해만 지나도`; `공부를 시작한 지 삼 년 정도 됐죠.` - `공부를 시작한 지 세 해 정도 됐죠.` You see what is awkward in these, don't you? I won't say they don't make sense, but they don't sound familiar to me.

Comment: It would be no problem to use `해` at all if you can manage to catch the subtle nuance differences, but if you can't, the easy way to go is just sticking to the more universal one.